# Problems building signature for Google Authentication

Tags: api, jwt, rsa, signature

I'm trying to make an authorized Google API call using a JWT.

But when I send the request I get this error:

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}

I'm following this manual https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest

The JWT consists of three parts: header, claim set and signature. The header is always the same for authentication and I set every neccessary parameter in the claim set.

Now for the signature it says that you have to encode the header and claim set using Base64url and concatenate them together with a period: {Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}

Then you sign this using SHA256withRSA and encode the result as well using Base64url again. After that you get the JWT also by concatenating them together: {Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}

But when I send the request using the JWT I always get the said error. I also tried encoding it first and then signing it but I get the same result.

Am I creating the signature correctly?
If so does anyone have an idea what else the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

So with the information you provided, your signature is invalid.

You can use https://jwt.io debugger to validate your token and compare the `Base64url` results.